# How do I get a dataframe from the boxplot outliers?

Tags: r, dataframe, boxplot, outliers

I would like to get the extreme values of columns in a data frame. To do this I am using the boxplot function. However, I cannot get the dataframe with the outliers and colunm names in a dataframe. How do I combine the output of the boxplot function (lists) into a dataframe?

```r
data_numeric <- select_if(data, is.numeric) 
boxplot_data <- boxplot(data_numeric)
```

example data:

```r
dataDummy = data.frame(c(1:10, 100, 110))
colnames(dataDummy) <-c('nameofcol')
```

The output I would like here is a dataframe linking 100 and 110 to nameofcol.

Comment: you could `data.frame(outliers = boxplot(c(1:10, 100, 110))$out)`

Comment: @jpsmith sadly, no. This returns the list with outliers as well. I need a data frame that connects the outliers to the row and column of the origial df.

Comment: @I_O I get the following error: Error in x[floor(d)] + x[ceiling(d)] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator

Answer (score 0):

A first approach might use `%in%` to match outliers with the original data. In fact, with *this* data, it works:

```r
dataDummy$out <- dataDummy$nameofcol %in% boxplot_data$out
dataDummy
#    nameofcol   out
# 1          1 FALSE
# 2          2 FALSE
# 3          3 FALSE
# 4          4 FALSE
# 5          5 FALSE
# 6          6 FALSE
# 7          7 FALSE
# 8          8 FALSE
# 9          9 FALSE
# 10        10 FALSE
# 11       100  TRUE
# 12       110  TRUE
```

However, with [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) and related to [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/3358272), this may not always work:

```r
(0.1 + 0.05) %in% 0.15
# [1] FALSE
```

so we can take a slightly more expensive way to test for a tolerance (say, 1e-9), and use that.

```r
abs((0.1 + 0.05) - 0.15) < 1e-9
# [1] TRUE
```

One way to use this is with `outer`:

```r
dataDummy$out2 <- rowSums(abs(outer(dataDummy$nameofcol, boxplot_data$out, `-`)) < 1e-9) > 0
dataDummy
#    nameofcol   out  out2
# 1          1 FALSE FALSE
# 2          2 FALSE FALSE
# 3          3 FALSE FALSE
# 4          4 FALSE FALSE
# 5          5 FALSE FALSE
# 6          6 FALSE FALSE
# 7          7 FALSE FALSE
# 8          8 FALSE FALSE
# 9          9 FALSE FALSE
# 10        10 FALSE FALSE
# 11       100  TRUE  TRUE
# 12       110  TRUE  TRUE
```

(Only `out2` is required, I made a second column just for comparison.)

---

**EDIT**: if you have multiple columns, then you can provide an aggregate column ("this row has at least one outlier") or multiple columns. Let me try both. First, I'll improve the sample data.

```r
dataDummy = data.frame(col1 = c(1:10, 100, 110), col2 = rev(c(1:10, 100, 110)))
boxplot(dataDummy, plot = FALSE)$out
# [1] 100 110 110 100
```

So that `$out` is not very helpful, clearly, we need to know from which column each of those came. So we need to do the boxplot calcs for each column. Let's try this:

```r
boxplots <- lapply(dataDummy, boxplot.stats)
str(boxplots)
# List of 2
#  $ col1:List of 4
#   ..$ stats: num [1:5] 1 3.5 6.5 9.5 10
#   ..$ n    : int 12
#   ..$ conf : num [1:2] 3.76 9.24
#   ..$ out  : num [1:2] 100 110
#  $ col2:List of 4
#   ..$ stats: num [1:5] 1 3.5 6.5 9.5 10
#   ..$ n    : int 12
#   ..$ conf : num [1:2] 3.76 9.24
#   ..$ out  : num [1:2] 110 100
```

With this we get a better clue how to proceed. If you don't need the intermediate values above, just to know outlier/not-outlier, then we can do

```r
are_outliers <- sapply(dataDummy, function(z) rowSums(abs(outer(z, boxplot.stats(z)$out, `-`)) < 1e-9) > 0)
are_outliers
#        col1  col2
#  [1,] FALSE  TRUE
#  [2,] FALSE  TRUE
#  [3,] FALSE FALSE
#  [4,] FALSE FALSE
#  [5,] FALSE FALSE
#  [6,] FALSE FALSE
#  [7,] FALSE FALSE
#  [8,] FALSE FALSE
#  [9,] FALSE FALSE
# [10,] FALSE FALSE
# [11,]  TRUE FALSE
# [12,]  TRUE FALSE
dataDummy$has_outlier <- rowSums(are_outliers) > 0
dataDummy
#    col1 col2 has_outlier
# 1     1  110        TRUE
# 2     2  100        TRUE
# 3     3   10       FALSE
# 4     4    9       FALSE
# 5     5    8       FALSE
# 6     6    7       FALSE
# 7     7    6       FALSE
# 8     8    5       FALSE
# 9     9    4       FALSE
# 10   10    3       FALSE
# 11  100    2        TRUE
# 12  110    1        TRUE
```

If instead you need to add multiple columns (one for each numeric column), you can do

```r
are_outliers <- lapply(dataDummy, function(z) rowSums(abs(outer(z, boxplot.stats(z)$out, `-`)) < 1e-9) > 0)
str(are_outliers)
# List of 2
#  $ col1: logi [1:12] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
#  $ col2: logi [1:12] TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
names(are_outliers) <- paste0("_out", names(are_outliers))
cbind(dataDummy, are_outliers)
#    col1 col2 _outcol1 _outcol2
# 1     1  110    FALSE     TRUE
# 2     2  100    FALSE     TRUE
# 3     3   10    FALSE    FALSE
# 4     4    9    FALSE    FALSE
# 5     5    8    FALSE    FALSE
# 6     6    7    FALSE    FALSE
# 7     7    6    FALSE    FALSE
# 8     8    5    FALSE    FALSE
# 9     9    4    FALSE    FALSE
# 10   10    3    FALSE    FALSE
# 11  100    2     TRUE    FALSE
# 12  110    1     TRUE    FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, however if you do this for 500 variables it is not readable. That is why I am looking to combine the outcome of the boxplot lists.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *"not readable"*, nor do I know what you mean by *"boxplot lists"*. Perhaps you should edit your question to better reflect what you're trying to do, your `dataDummy` has only one variable.

Comment: Okay, I think I get it ... you need outliers _per column_. Yes, you're going to need to edit your question (I suggest adding one or two columns to your `dataDummy`, as it does not reflect what you're seeking). You also need to add explicitly what you need added. For instance, is it one column where that row has _at least_ one outlier? Or is it one new logical column for each numeric column, indicating if _that_ column on _that_ row was an outlier?

Comment: @nemja, see my edit, I think it will do more for you. (It also changes to using `boxplot.stats`, perhaps a little faster for determining outliers.)

Comment: Thanks so much for thinking with me on this! However, I think you are right. I need to rephrase the question.  The question has do to with combining the output of boxplot$out with the column names and the group variable. So I will think how to phrase that and come back with a better question.